# how to test classification data set in WEKA?

Tags: weka

I have a big data set that contains the last attribute class label as text.

I am using Weka for training classification using the J48 decision tree.  60% of the data set is used for Training and 40% for testing.   How do I predict the class in Weka?

I put the class of '?' rather than the class in the last attribute and I want to predict it.  Why does the confusion matrix output zero and the total number of instances equal zero?

I selected 'more option' and then “Output predictions” as “plain text” to show the results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to predict.  If you are trying to predict the last attribute, you should select the last attribute for training.  Could you please describe the problem in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

In the Weka explorer,

- go to the "Classify" panel,
- click in the select-box on the left, located between the "More options..." button and the "Start" button.
- After clicking on the selectbox, the list expands. Choose the column that you are trying to predict.

If that column has an inappropriate datatype, that your algorithm of choice cannot handle, then the "Start..." button will inactive and be greyed out.

Then go to the "Preprocess" panel, and add an attribute filter, e.g "StringToNominal". (Or do something else to your data.)